# Scala list contains vs array contains

Tags: scala

Out of interest why does this work in Scala:

```
val exceptions = List[Char]('+')    
assertTrue(exceptions.contains('+'))
```

but this not

```
val exceptions = new Array[Char]('+')    
assertTrue(exceptions.contains('+'))
```

Comment: This would be a great Scala Puzzler!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you wrote **new** ArrayChar. Doing that, the argument is the size of the array, and the '+' is, rather unfortunately, converted to an int to give the size. And the returned array is full of Char(0).

You should just do `Array[Char]('+')`, `'+'` would then be single element in the Array.

Answer (score 7):

Try in the REPL, that makes the answer obvious:

```
scala> val exceptions = new Array[Char]('+')
exceptions: Array[Char] = Array( ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  )
```

`+` has char-to-int promotion.

```
scala> val exceptions = Array[Char]('+')
exceptions: Array[Char] = Array(+)

scala> exceptions.contains('+')
res3: Boolean = true
```

is the equivalent to the `List` case.